# Prove that the product of three consecutive natural numbers is divisible by 6

Tags: proof-writing, natural-numbers

My math teacher asked me this question, and I told him that in every three consecutive natural numbers we have one multiple of 3, and at least two multiples of 2. And for a number to be divisible by 6, we need it to be both divisible by 3 and 2. He said that this proof was correct, but it was not strong enough because I had used Induction. And I should use Inference. How can I prove this using Inference?

Comment: $4+ 5 + 6 = 15$, so you can't prove it.

Comment: @Carl Sorry, I had an error and instead of “product” I had written “sum”

Comment: There's only one multiple of $2$ among  $5,6,7$. Not that it matters, one is enough. Regarding your question: It's not at all clear how a correct proof can be "not strong enough". Also I don't see where you used induction. And the notion of proving something "using Inference" means very little to me...

Comment: It's not clear what the critique means. But to be rigorous you need to *prove* the claims about products of consecutive integers being divisible by $2$ and $3$. Also what you wrote is imprecise enough that it could be interpreted as $\,6\mid n\,\Rightarrow\ 2,3\mid n\,$ but you need the *reverse* implication (which also requires *proof*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This part is an answer to the initial question** (asking for the *SUM* instead of the *Product*)

Three consecutive natural numbers are $n-1,n,n+1$ and their sum is $3n.$ 
But if $n$ is odd, this sum is not divisible by $6.$

**Answer related to the PRODUCT:**

Product of three consecutive natural numbers is $(n-1)n(n+1)=n^3-n.$ Denote it $P.$

1. If $n$ is even ($n=2k$), then $n^3=8k^3$ is even and $P$ is even as the difference of two even numbers.
   Similarly, if $n$ is odd, then $n^3$ is odd and the difference of two odd numbers is even.

We conclude that $P$ is even (divisible by $2$).

2. For divisibility by $3,$ consider the $3$ cases:

   - $n\equiv0\pmod3,$ then $n^3\equiv 0\pmod{3},$ from where $P\equiv 0\pmod 3;$
   - $n\equiv 1\pmod{3},$ then $n^3\equiv 1\pmod3,$ which gives $P\equiv 0\pmod 3;$
   - $n\equiv 2 \pmod 3,$ then $n^3\equiv 2 \pmod 3$ and we have again $P\equiv 0\pmod 3.$

Conclusion: $P$ is divisible by $2$ and by $3$, therefore is divisible by $6.$

Comment: The answer does not apply since the question is clearly about the *product* (not the *sum*) -  as the edit verifies.

Comment: Anyway, the approach is more than useful for the product as well. I didn't want to underestimate Sean, in my answer are both: indication that there is apparently a lapsus in his formulation, and a hint.

Comment: @Maam I don´t see how your answer helps solve the question.

Comment: The question was about the sum when this was posted - the OP should not make such drastic changes in their post that it renders previously correct answers incorrect!

Comment: @Carl's point is well-taken.  The above Answer was correct (and provides a useful method for analysis) at the time it was posted (some five minutes before Carl pointed out the flaw in the Question via a Comment).  I think this is OK.

Comment: Isn´t there a rule at MSE that OP should not edit their question so that the answers already posted become non valid?

Comment: @user376343 Yes, there is such a rule, but there is pretty much an exception for "typos" and this applies here. I would just edit your answer with a remark that it relates to a previous version of the question, in order not to confuse anyone.

Comment: ok @MichaelGreinecker I'm going to adapt my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Out of three consecutive numbers you will always find an even number and a multiple of three. By multiplying, you get a multiple of 6.

---

Here is another proof:

Let $n$ a natural. $n\times (n+1) \times (n+2)=n^3+3n^2+2n$

If $n \equiv 1 \pmod 2$, $n^3+3n \equiv 0 \pmod 2$.

If $n \equiv 0 \pmod 2$, $n^3+3n \equiv 0 \pmod 2$.

You can do the same reasoning modulo 3.

Finally, $n^3+3n^2+2n \equiv 0 \pmod{2\times 3}\Leftrightarrow \exists p \in \mathbb{N}, n(n+1)(n+2)=6p$

Comment: Here is another proof